# adding elements to firebase realtime database using Trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase cloud function to trigger a database update when a field is created on my database.

```
exports.dbTest2 = functions.database.ref('/{uid}/ignore')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

        const uid = context.params.uid
        console.log(`Current User ${uid}`)

        // Data added at the location
        const ignoreData = snapshot.val()
        const endTime = new Date(ignoreData.endTime).toString()


        // ref matches `/{uid}/ignore`
        return snapshot.ref.parent.child('schedule').set({

                allDay: false,
                endDate: new Date().toString(),
                id: 100,
                startDate: new Date().toString(),
                title: 'test'

         })

    });
```

This function gets triggered when I add `ignore` to my real-time database. When this gets triggered, it looks like below:

[image]

However, I want `ignore` to be an array-like structure that has indices where each index contains the object. Something like this:

[image]

I also tried something like `return snapshot.ref.parent.child('schedule').child().set(...`

but didn't work because `child()` requires a parameter.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass an array with objects:

```
 return snapshot.ref.parent.child('schedule').set(
  [
    {
        allDay: false,
        endDate: new Date().toString(),
        id: 100,
        startDate: new Date().toString(),
        title: 'test1'
    },
    {
        allDay: false,
        endDate: new Date().toString(),
        id: 101,
        startDate: new Date().toString(),
        title: 'test2'
    }
  ]
 );
```

How it looks in my firebase(photos are passed as array): [image: firebase collection]